# Android Fragment/ViewPager - ViewGroups losing background color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using a ViewPager with a "Tabbed Activity" generated by Android Studio.

When I run the app, the right layouts are loaded into the right fragments and you can easily swipe between fragments. The layout is correct, with all the background colors set like they should.

Unfortunately, as soon as you swipe into another fragment, all `Layouts` (`ViewGroups`) lose their background color, which means that they become transparent. The views inside still look the same.

Example: The EditText at the bottom is inside a LinearLayout that should be white (left picture) but becomes grey (right picture).

Two screenshots: 1) on load and 2) after swiping

[image: normal] [image: buggy]

The strangest thing is, that if you swipe into a fragment and it loses the backgrounds, everything goes back to normal if you swipe a little to the left or right, without changing the tab.

What could be the problem?

## CODE

### Adapter

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 4 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "POS: " + position;
    }
}
```

### Fragment

```
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String WHICH = "WHICH";

    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */

    public PageFragment() {}

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int which){
        PageFragment page = new PageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(WHICH, which);
        page.setArguments(args);
        return page;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView;
        switch(getArguments().getInt(WHICH)){
            case 1:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_one, container, false);
                break;
            case 2:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_two, container, false);
                break;
            case 3:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_four, container, false);
                break;
            case 4:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_five, container, false);
                break;
            default:
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_defautlt, container, false);
                break;
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

### LinearLayout that has incorrect background:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".85"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_2"
            style="@style/inputDefault"
            android:minLines="1"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:gravity="start|center"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_medium"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin_medium"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/write_message"
            android:id="@+id/chatroom_editText" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".15"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
            style="@style/btnImage"
            android:id="@+id/chatroom_send_btn"
            android:onClick="sendItem"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:padding="0dp"
            />

</LinearLayout>

<style name="inputDefault">
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_small</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/grey_2</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/grey_3</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Share some code... specially your adapter and your fragment

Comment: @GuilhermeP thanks for helping. Code is there. As mentioned, this is basically nothing else than the generated stuff from Android Studio.

Comment: @Barthy both of them are black what is your problem ? it should be white and it's not ?

Comment: @Amir The EditText at the bottom is inside a LinearLayout that should be white (left picture) but becomes grey (right picture)

Comment: @Barthy Can you put EditText code

Comment: @Barthy is EditText exist in all fragments  or it's in your MainActivity?

Comment: @Amir added the layout's content. It exists only in one fragment. In other fragments, the same happens to other LinearLayouts.

Comment: @Barthy Put background of your EditText android:background="@null"

Comment: @Amir are you a wizard? That worked! Post it as an answer, preferably with an explanation haha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's not related to your `LinearLayout` or `TabActivity` or etc. It's usual behaviour of EditText.

If you want your `EditText` background be transparent or in your case white it's not necessary to define `android:background="@color/white"` just put background @null and rest of things will be Ok.

Comment: Bounty in 22 hours. Can you explain why margin is not transparent? Because the `EditText` should have only covered the center of its parent, with margin on top and bottom. The margin should have been transparent and showing the LinearLayout's background, or not?

Comment: @Barthy why it's should be transparent when you define margin? if you want what margin or padding you define and see what exactly happen just turn your layout bound on.

Comment: @settings->developer options --> show Layout bounds